# AngularJS - Get data immediatelly after call to query()

Tags: service, controller, angularjs

I have a Service

```
angular.module('AigServices', ['ngResource']).factory('aiguilleurs', function($resource){

var service = $resource('app/data/EpargneATermeRachetableCELI.json', {}, {
    query: {method:'GET', params:{}, isArray:true}});

return service;  });
```

In my controller, when I call `aiguilleurs.query()`, I receive the structure but no data like it said in the doc.  I want to have the data has soon has I call the `query()`.  Any idea?  I have looked around and didn't find anything.  So the controller code follow (`$scope.listeAiguilleurs[0]` is always undefined):

```
$scope.listeAiguilleurs = aiguilleurs.query();   
var questionEnCours = null;

if ($scope.listeAiguilleurs[0] != null) {
    questionEnCours = $scope.listeAiguilleurs[0].questions[$scope.noQuestionEnCours-1];
}
$scope.questionEnCours = questionEnCours;
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because the query returns a `promise`. You can read more about that [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q). You have to pass a callback to the function (check out the Credit Card Resource example [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource)). Try this:

```
$scope.listeAiguilleurs = aiguilleurs.query(function () {   
    var questionEnCours = null;

    if ($scope.listeAiguilleurs[0] != null) {
        questionEnCours = $scope.listeAiguilleurs[0].questions[$scope.noQuestionEnCours-1];
    }
    $scope.questionEnCours = questionEnCours;
});
```